# Explicit evaluation of symplectic form on cotangent bundle

Tags: differential-forms, symplectic-geometry, co-tangent-space

Let $M$ be a manifold and denote by $T^*M$ its cotangent bundle.
Let $(x,U)$ be a coordinate chart so that $x: U\to \mathbb{R}^{n}$.
Let $p\in U$ and $v\in T^*_pM$, then we can write
$v = v_i dx^i$
where $v_i=v(\partial_{x^i})$. More in general, a cotangent vector $w\in T^*M\vert_U$ is given by
$$
w = w_i dx^i
$$
where now $w_i:U\to \mathbb{R}$.
This defines a chart on $T^*M\vert_U$ via
$$
(x,y):T^*M\vert_U\to \mathbb{R}^{2n}\\
(p,v)\mapsto (x(p),v(\partial_{x^i})).
$$
All this is well known and so is the fact that
$$
\omega = dx\wedge dy = dx^i\wedge dy_i
$$
defines a symplectic structure on $T^*M$.

So we may consider curves $\gamma,\sigma: \mathbb{R} \to T^*M$ going through $(p,v)\in T^*M\vert_U$ at time $0$ and evaluate $\omega$ at $\dot{\gamma}(0),\dot{\sigma}(0)$.

My question is: how do we compute $\omega_{(p,v)}(\dot{\gamma}(0),\dot{\sigma}(0))$ explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

I consider an explicit example with given curves and charts. The general case follows from changing the notation.

Let $M=S^1$, $x^1$ the "projection left" of $S^1\cap\{u^1>0\}$ and
$$
\gamma_0(t)=(\cos(at),\sin(at))\\
\sigma_0(t)=(\cos(bt),\sin(bt))
$$
for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Then a possible curve in $T^*M$ is given by
$$
\gamma(t) = (\gamma_0(t),f(\gamma_0(t))dx) \in \Gamma_{\gamma_0}(T^*M)
$$
for some $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$ and we do similarly with $\sigma$ using a function $g:M\to\mathbb{R}$.

Let's now evaluate $\omega$. We first compute
$$
dx^1\dot{\gamma}(0)= \frac{d}{dt}\vert_{t=0}x^1\gamma_0(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\vert_{t=0} \sin(at)=a
$$
while
$$
dy^1\dot{\gamma}(0)= \frac{d}{dt}\vert_{t=0}\gamma(t)\partial_{x^1}=\frac{d}{dt}\vert_{t=0} f\gamma_0(t)=(df) \dot{\gamma}_0(0).
$$

So if for example $f:S^1\to \mathbb{R}$ sends $(u^1,u^2)\mapsto \alpha u^2$ and $g:S^1\to \mathbb{R}$ sends $(u^1,u^2)\mapsto \beta u^2$ we get
$$
\omega(\dot{\gamma}(0),\dot{\sigma}(0)) = ab\beta-ba\alpha.
$$

Comment: Why is $M= \mathbb S^1$?

Comment: As said, I just worked out an example in order to get concrete values at the end. But the same procedure works for any manifold.